# Understanding THIS in Javascript, i got lost

Tags: javascript, this, primitive-types

So i am messing around with Javascript and one thing caught my attention.

The variable THIS, and working on it i was wondering, if i have this function:

```
var someFn = function(){ console.log(this); }
```

and i run someFn() obviously it will console the Window, but is there, anyway i can make that exact same function console a string? And not a object?

I've tried many ways, even:

```
someFn.call("A Nice String");
```

But it will break the string into an object on each letter.

Is there any way?

Comment: It does not break the string into an object on each letter - it logs a **single `String` object** - whose representation in your dev tool console contains numerical indicies corresponding to each letter

Comment: Oh it makes sense. Gotcha!

Answer (score 3):

In loose mode, `this` is always an object. Strings, numbers and booleans will be wrapped (which is what you see, an array-like [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object), `null` and `undefined` will be replaced with the global object (`window` in browsers).

If you use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), it will work as expected:

```
function someFn(){ "use strict"; console.log(this); }
someFn(); // undefined
someFn.call("A nice string"); // A nice string
```

Comment: That completely works, thank you for the strict mode link too, is really REALLY helpful.

Comment: what different is happening when you are using strict mode?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem in the past, it seems to insist on logging out the object with each letter as parts of the array.

I ended up cheating and using something like:

```
console.log(this+'')
```

or

```
console.log(this.toString());
```

Comment: It doesn't log an array, it logs a `String` object - type this in your console: `new String('Hello World')` and you'll see what a `String` object looks like.